# Calculating the determinant of a large sparse matrix with symbolic entries - but Matrix does not accept polynomial entries

Tags: python, sympy, sparse-matrix, symbolic-math, determinants

I'm trying to calculate the determinant of an 84*84 matrix which is fairly sparse (about 400 non zero elements, about 40 rows have only 1 nonzero element).

I was able to do it by using the `berkowitz` method - but I cannot seem to do anything with the computed determinant. I am unable to access the computed determinant in any way - printing gets stuck for hours, simple substitutions also stuck for hours, converting `expr` to `poly` also stuck for hours etc.

I figured that using polynomial entries in the `Matrix` might speed this up, but I believe non-expr objects in a matrix are deprecated..

What can I do as a workaround? To be able to calculate the determinant, I need to use `Matrix` - but to be able to do anything with that determinant I need it to be `poly` not `expr`; and those two requirements are not commensurate with each other..

Is using Mathematica a better idea?

EDIT: Added an image of the matrix whose determinant I am trying to calculate. When I calculate the determinant, I use the symbols m0 to m24. Sympy does this. Eventually I want to be able to make the substitutions as listed in the lines below the matrix.

[image]

Comment: Great problem. Looks like the matrix is strongly patterned; is it something created by a template for a numerical method or something like that? One approach is to try induction on the size of the matrix -- can you express the determinant for size = k in terms of the determinant for size k - 1? (I'm guessing the matrix size increases 6 or 7 at a time or something.)

Comment: FWIW Stackoverflow is mostly for programming problems, and although there's programming involved here, I'm guessing this is largely a mathematical problem. Maybe try math.stackexchange.com instead.